# Update in DB column vlaues using django script

Tags: sql, django, sql-update

I have to update in DB table column name batch_status
for which I have written the SQL query
here

```
UPDATE farm_management_batch 
set batch_status = "running"
where start_date < now()
and batch_status = "to_start"


UPDATE farm_management_batch 
set batch_status = "completed"
where batch_status IN ('to_start', 'running')
and expected_delivery_date < now()
```

But now I want to write a Django script for this
which I have no idea how to do it

Here Is the Screenshot
[image: DB SCreenshot]

Comment: Will this be a repeatable task or once in a lifetime thing?

Comment: to add to @MohamedElKalioby 's comment since your are using MySQL if it is a repeatable task you could consider using MySQL [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to define models.py for the following table. Let's asume the model name is **FarmManagementBatch**.

The first query will be as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

FarmManagementBatch.objects.filter(batch_status='to_start', start_date__lt=dt.now()).update(batch_status='running')
```

Second query will be as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

FarmManagementBatch.objects.filter(expected_delivery_date__lt=dt.now(), batch_status__in=['to_start', 'running']).update(batch_status='completed')
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this but now I DO I need to create and write a script file for this In Batch/script/
file 
like I have added and pic of script Please check

Comment: No, you don't have to write a batch script. Just call this during your views function. Might I ask, What are you using django for?

Comment: Or If I do not want to change on the model bases I want to write a separate script for this

Comment: You need to create models for using the Django ORM. That's why I am asking what are you making on your Django project?

Comment: I want to update my DB on daily bases for that I am writing a script where I connect to my and run an update command to make changes in my DB

Comment: I already have an model written with all the columns and table names